# Code organization (node, js involving models, service, route and mocha tests)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm quite a beginner in the project architecturing / structuring side of things.

The overall project currently looks like:

- route/home.js
- service/appService.js
- models/appModel.js

In the route file, I require appService.js.
appService.js takes care of some API calls to external services, such as getting an access_token from such API service.

When I receive the access token, a callback is made in appService which calls appModel (appService requires appModel.js), and in turn appModel stores the access token in the database. Then, another callback is called in appService which in turn does runs the callback that the route page provided, then  I make a redirection.

I am using mocha for testing the service and model files.
My service file is requiring the model file, so when I create a mocha test for the service file, the model is called indirectly as well.

Should I require the model in my route file instead of the service file, and run the model function in the route, once I receive the access token response from the API in the service file? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would have some kind of bootstrapper or service container which handles loading your files.

That way you avoid tight couplings between the different parts of your application and can exchange them out when testing (such as swapping the DB for fixtures).